# NextJS conditional CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

Came across this when creating an animated dropdown for a navbar.

In a strict React implementation, an inline if/else statement can be used with an onClick toggle to set and remove CSS animation styles. In order to provide a default styling (with no animation) for when state is null, a class can be added before the inline if/else operation:

```
<div className={`navbar ${reactState ? "expanded" : "collapsed"}`}>
```

How do I replicate this in NextJS?

I can't find anything in the documentation and have blindly attempted the following (unsuccessfully):

```
<div className={styles.navbar (reactState ? `${styles.expanded}` : `${styles.collapsed}`)}>
```

```
<div className={styles.navbar [reactState ? `${styles.expanded}` : `${styles.collapsed}`]}>
```

```
<div className={styles.navbar `${reactState ? `${styles.expanded}` : `${styles.collapsed}`}`}>
```

The only success I've had is with the following, which seems like overkill:

```
<div className={
  reactState != null ?
    (reactState ? `${styles.navbar} ${styles.expanded}` 
    : `${styles.navbar} ${styles.collapsed}`)
  : styles.navbar
}>
```

I'm clearly not fully understanding how NextJS handles React styling. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It works exactly the same as in normal React, see [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support). But you have got an error with your string interpolation, you'll see the missing spaces if you open up the dev tools. E.g. ` `${styles.expanded}` ` --> `styles.expanded`

Comment: Can you please tell me, How you imported the CSS file. I will guide you to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, and it works as same as React. Only you didn't escape the values correctly.

```
<div className={`${styles.navbar} ${reactState ? styles.expanded : styles.collapsed}`}>...</div>
```